# Open login for inside modal dialog for Joomla 2.5

Tags: forms, joomla, dialog, modal-dialog, joomla2.5

So I have a specific page that spawns a modal dialog to login/register. I am using Colorbox, and this is working nicely for me. What I need to do is open ONLY the form and not the entire page with header links and such. I understand this can be fixed by adding '?tmpl=component' or '&tmpl=component' to the end of the url. My problem is that my form is stripped of all styling and is terribly ugly. Is there any way I can go about adding styling back to this form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Outdated? Joomla 2.5 is still the current Long Term Release version ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the entire FTP and did a search for where the basic stylesheets were being included (general.css and system.css) so that I could add my others for style. This can be found/edited in public_html/templates/system/component.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get all styles,

This is happen due to using with `tmpl=component` Normally Joomla using this layout for printing purpose(Print layout) it have only basic styling compared to your default template `index.php`.

So you need to get your proper styling for the forms you have to add those style sheet to the `component.php` inside your template folder.

```
templates/your_template/component.php
```

Add your basic template style sheet at the top of the file using same like `index.php`.

eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/beez_20/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
```

Then `tmpl=component` view have proper styles applied.

Hope it helps..

Comment: This isn't working for me unfortunately, do you know where the /templates/system/css/system.css and /templates/system/css/general.css are being initiated? These are styling my blank component forms, and I could add my other stylesheets here (rather than editing these).

Comment: It will work you have to set the style sheet path properly on your template./templates/system/css/system.css and /templates/system/css/general.css are your CSS then check those folders inside template ->system->css->files add this path inside your component.php file then it tooks the styles.